# How to get physical file path using IFormFile?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Is it possible to get the file path where the file is belong to usign IFromfile?
My API location is `"D:\\Development\\XenterAPI"` and my file location is `"C:\\image\\demo.png"`.

When I select a file from swagger, it returns me this `"D:\\Development\\XenterAPI\demo.png"`. But I need like this, `"C:\\image\\demo.png"`.

Is it possible to get this? Please help me. I am stuck with this.

Comment: `IFormFile` doesn't expose source file location to client

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, Is there any other way to get it?